# What does the locked icon mean on a chat room?

Tags: support, chat

Recently I navigated to the SO chat, and I noticed some of chat rooms have a Locked icon at Top Left side corner.

What does this locked icon mean?

[image]

Comment: When in doubt, hover! 90% of the times it will tell you what the icon/element is doing. :)

Comment: @ShadowWizard I am often hovering...not sure how I got up here though...

Comment: Oh, and -1 for no free hand shapes in the screenshot! :D

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you hover over the padlock, it says:

> Gallery: anyone may enter, but only approved users can talk

Essentially, a semi private chat room, a lot of the times for specific topics between 2 or more members (I would imagine an attempt to keep it on topic as much as possible).  If you click on the room, there is a button to request access.

Comment: @omean Thnx for info

Answer (score 3):

It indicates that the room mode is Gallery.

If room mode is **Public**, anyone may enter and talk.
If room mode is **Gallery**, anyone may enter, but only approved users can talk.

[image]

The "Request Access" button is displayed at the bottom of the page, if you enter a chat room which is in Gallery mode.

[image]

Comment: @IR Where i find this access request?